# How to override an action in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to override an action method in  a controller? Can anyone explain with a small example.
And one more thing to ask , can we do this without virtual keyword?

Comment: Do you mean override or overload? If overload - basically you can have single method per each METHOD type (Get, Post, etc). If override - what's the issue you have, what you have done so far?

Comment: Can you be more detailed? Have you got a base controller? (I'm not the down voter :))

Comment: In my solution one method i need to override.Actually that one is not defined as virtual.  I need to do with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i m understanding your question these are the answers :

**First Answer :**

it's not possible to have two controller actions with the same name but with a different result also:

For example:

```
ActionResult YourAction() { ... }
FileContentResult YourAction() { ... }
```

In MVC you can also do this :

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("AnyAction")]
ActionResult YourAction(firstModel model1) { ... }

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("AnyAction")]
FileContentResult YourAction(secondModel model1) { ... }
```

The main idea here is that you can use the ActionNameAttribute to name several action methods with the same name.

----------------------------------------------------------------OR--------------------------------------------------------------

**Second Answer :**

```
[NonAction]
public override ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection form)
{
  // do nothing or throw exception
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection form)
{
  // your implementation
}
```

Comment: what?  You can't have two identical method signatures like that, it won't compile

Comment: Your 'First Answer' won't compile.  You can't have two methods with the same name and parameters in C#, regardless of return type or attribute decoration

Comment: parameters are different just see carefully..@Jonesy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same as how the Filters will hook into it when you use filters in an mvc solution

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
   if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("api-key", out var value))
   {
      ///
   }
   base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```