# .Net MVC: How to correct <Form> fields in a post request for a different data model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, post

**How can you send a form in a POST request, to another data model (not the one in the view)?**

I have UserModel and FilterRequest Models.

To filter the data do I need to post a request to an IndexFilter with a FilterRequest filtering model?

*Help Please, how can I do this?*

View/User/Index.cshtml

```
@model UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexFilter", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name ="pageNumber" value="@Model.PaginationModel.PageNumber"/>

    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterData.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterData.LastName)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

UserController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult IndexFilter([FromBody] FilterRequest request)
{

}
```

UserModel.cs

```
public class UserModel
{
    public IList<User> Users{ get; set; }
    
    public PaginationModel PaginationModel { get; set; }

    public FilterData FilterData { get; set; }
}
```

FilterRequest.cs

```
public class FilterRequest
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;

    public FilterData FilterData { get; set; }
}
```

**A Post request is sent to the server, with Form Data**
`pageNumber=1&FilterData.FirstName=&FilterData.LastName=Nikita&__RequestVerificationToken=Token`
The server replied with 415.

Comment: *"How can you send a form in a POST request, to another data model (not the one in the view)?"* Just add new controller method to receive the exact model you have in the view. You want to post `UserModel` to server then just add a new action method `[HttpPost]
public IActionResult IndexFilter(UserModel request)`

Comment: But I don't need the "UserModel" view model. I need a model for filtering data (FilterRequest).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override an action in mvc controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058585/how-to-override-an-action-in-mvc-controller)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I want to put together in a form the model I need to filter the data. So that the action can take it `[HttpPost] public IActionResult IndexFilter([FromBody] FilterRequest request)`

Comment: Now when I send a post request in the form, the method in the controller cannot accept it

Comment: In that case you can create new parent viewmodel that contains both models. One action method IndexFilter receives that object and depending on the form you posted, one model would be null and the other one would contain data.

Comment: Use same field name in other model properties to auto binding, else you can get data manually from request header. and in your code request sent data from query parameter not form body

Comment: I use the same fields for automatic linking ... but for some reason it doesn't link them @AliPanahian

Comment: @Nikita, if the form contains a field that is no present in model, binder would raise error. Event when there are other fields that do match. Try posting only `FilterData` from your view. Both `UserModel` and `FilterRequest` has this. All you have to do is removing `pageNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Change to `[FromForm]`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult IndexFilter([FromForm] FilterRequest request)
    {
        //...
        return Ok();
    }
```

> Test Code

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            UserModel user = new UserModel()
            {

                PaginationModel = new PaginationModel { PageNumber = 100 },
                FilterData = new FilterData { FirstName = "Ada", LastName = "Michael" }
            };
            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult IndexFilter([FromForm] FilterRequest request)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

> Screenshot of Debugging

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please tell me, how do you send data to html

Comment: Sorry, @Nikita, I didn't get your point of sending data to html. Could u detail you needs？ so that I can help u.